# Animate on $stateTransition (both exit and enter)

Tags: angularjs, animation, angular-ui-router

I have figured out how to make animations happen by using $stateChangeStart or $stateChangeSuccess in a controller or in my main apps $stateProvider but I can't get it to work as I intend to.

I would like to initiate a solid color bar that wipes over the screen and then wipes back the other direction showing the content. I imagine that when I click a menu link the animation begins(wiping over the current page), once at full-width -> the static page or data-binded page/controller is loaded and rendered and then once that is complete the animation swipes back the other way revealing the new page content.

I need help understanding how to make sure that every time a link is clicked: the first animation happens/ page is loaded/ and the next page revealed.

Comment: if you can wait, `$stateEnter` and `$stateExit` event handlers are in [progress](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1835) already. but for now, I think you have to do the manual way (and there are plenty ways of doing it)

Comment: @CozyAzure I would love some insight in how to manually hold loading the new page template and check that it is loaded.

Comment: that would be lots of ways to achieve is. Use `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` is one good way. If you want to make sure the page is loaded with your data, then probably you need to look into `resolve`, and use simply `ng-show` or hide to animate all the CSS

Comment: @CozyAzure i'm having a difficult time figuring this all out. If there was any way you could provide an example, I would be ever so grateful.